# how to insert two dates into one column as two rows using trigger mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert two dates in one column as two rows using mysql trigger. Is there any way to do so? If there is, please let me know!

My code for creating trigger

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `after_emp_insert` 
    AFTER INSERT
     ON `employee_master`
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
    INSERT INTO time_line(tl_dob, tl_dob, tl_name, tl_message, tl_message)
    VALUES(new.em_DOB, new.em_DOJ, new.em_first_name, 'Happy Birth Day', 'Congrats');
```

Comment: If you want to write 2 rows then write 2 insert statements. I am a bit puzzled why you would want to write dob and doj to dob and how you would know which was which later.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSE!!!